# Run a batch after callout is finish

Tags: apex, batch, callout, webservices

**My process -**

I have a process in which I send data to outer system - and get a JSON to insert into Salesforce. This is handled by a scheduled class once a week.

**The Received JSON: - (Could be ~7K Contact).**

```
{
    "Contact": [{
        "Name": "emxampleName",
        "Email": "example@gmail.com",
        "Age": 123456789,
        "contact_External_Id":"123456",
        "Courses": [{
            "Name": 12354678,
            "Contact_Person": 2,
            "Exam_Date": 1234567
        }],
        "Scholarship": [{
            "Name": "U",
            "donor_Name": 1234,
            "Total_Sum": "5000"
        }]
    }]
}
```

For the Scholarship & Courses Objects (Also objects in salesforce which Contact is the parent) I should check if I need to insert or update the Data, base on a few keys
For the Contact itself - only with one external field key - so I can use UPSERT.

I thought to Insert all the contacts first - without the Courses and Scholarship - and send to the batch all the Ids of the upserted contact.

After that, inside the batch - for each contact -  I will seek the "contact_External_Id" and check if I will need to insert\update the Scholarship & Courses.

**My questions -**

1. Until now I used Future method with callout to run the request and get the data - but since I need to push the data to a batch and run the query on the set of the contact Ids - I can't use this method anymore (Can't call Batch from future method).
   How can I achieve it?
2. This process solution sounds a bit lame. If you guys have a better solution - It will be much appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as using a Queueable with Database.AllowsCallouts instead of using a future method. See the [product documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) for details.

There are lots of alternatives you could consider in terms of the over-all approach, such as generating platform events with the JSON (as text) in them, but this approach does keep it clean and simple.

Comment: Thank You Phil :)